# Is an application hosted on a VM within the cloud still an "on-premises" application according to this Microsoft documentation?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, microsoft

Wikipedia defines [on-premises software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software) as the following: (elipse mine)

> On-premises software [...] is installed and runs on computers on the premises of the person or organization using the software, rather than at a remote facility such as a server farm or cloud

Which would mean that a SQL server running in a VM on the cloud is an off-premises application.

[This Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/on-premises-sql-connector-configure) describes provisioning to a SQL-based application.

This guide is under the on-premises category. No guide exists for provisioning to an off-premises SQL-based application. Using this guide for a SQL server on a VM within Azure still functions, but for some issues that I believe are unrelated.

Does that mean the SQL server should be considered an on-premises application, despite Wikipedia defining it as off-premises?

Are Microsoft referring to a different definition of "on-premises?"

Answer (score 2):

### Microsoft’s documentation is mixed up.

#### That linked documentation is horribly confused and seems to be legacy documentation “hacked” to add off-premises concepts and terminology.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/on-premises-sql-connector-configure) seems like a mixed up mess. Let’s break it down; two very simple reasons:

1. **URL Fragment is Wrong**: The [actual URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/on-premises-sql-connector-configure) is clearly a relic of past draft. Look at the URL itself: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/on-premises-sql-connector-configure` and look at that last fragment `on-premises-sql-connector-configure`. Why is it that when the title of the doc is “Provisioning users into SQL based applications?”
2. **18 (!!!) Uses of “On-Premises” in the Doc**: Do an in-page browser search on that page at it shows 18 uses of the “on-premises” qualifier when it could easily be removed. For example the heading “[On-premises prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/on-premises-sql-connector-configure#on-premises-prerequisites)” could just be “Prerequisites” without changing any meaning. The same can be said for practically all other uses on that page; remove “on-premises” and the content’s meaning is 100% the same.

Thus you ask:

> “This guide is under the on-premises category. No guide exists for provisioning to an off-premises SQL-based application. Using this guide for a SQL server on a VM within Azure still functions, but for some issues that I believe are unrelated.”

Yes, you correctly surmised that the guide works for on-premises and off-premises purposes. But you also say:

> “Does that mean the SQL server should be considered an on-premises application, despite Wikipedia defining it as off-premises?”

Nope! An on-premises application is physically on site. The off-premises application is in the cloud or off site. That inherent difference does not change.

> Are Microsoft referring to a different definition of "on-premises?"

Microsoft has mixed-up documentation that seems to have been initially written for on-premises purpose and then was badly edited to shoehorn in cloud concepts. Instead of managing the URLs by redirects, they seem to have lazily retained the old URL and old verbiage.

But as stated before, an on-premises application is physically on site. The off-premises application is in the cloud or off site. That inherent difference does not change.

---

**Note**: Apparently all of Microsoft’s documentation is hosted on GitHub; this specific page is [supposedly managed here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/entra-docs/blob/main/docs/identity/app-provisioning/on-premises-sql-connector-configure.md). I say “supposedly” because as a mere mortal (aka: non-Microsoft employee) I have attempted to fork the repo and edit it to correct it.

But I have no idea where the actual doc is; it seems to be the repo is partially transparent where edits are shown but the actual document is hidden? Regardless, it needs to be edited to remove the unneeded/confusing reference to “on premises.”

Answer (score 0):

In that Microsoft Document:

- **On-Premises requirements** refers to what's required in the environment where you're running the SQL provisioning agent software (OS, DB version, RAM, etc). It doesn't matter whether it's hosted in the cloud
- **Cloud requirements** refers to what you'll need on the cloud (Entra ID) side, like license, admin role, and user accounts to provision

It's not an either/or requirement - it's just clarifying what is required on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the terminology that is used, here are some partial
excerpts that describe the three terms that describe
where an SQL installation is installed, from the article
[What is the difference between on-premise, hosted and cloud solutions?](https://gosmarthr.com/blog/business-impact/what-is-the-difference-between-on-premise-hosted-and-cloud-solutions/)

> **On-premise**
>
> The SQL DB can be installed on the customer’s premises on a server
> managed by their IT department.  This is referred to as an on-premise
> model.  In this case, the IT department are responsible for managing
> the hardware, backing up the database, and upgrading applications as
> part of the organisational data management strategy. At all times, the
> customer owns the database as part of their SQL instance.
>
> **Hosted**
>
> Alternatively, the customer could choose to host the SQL DB at a data
> center managed by a third party.  In this case, the customer maintains
> ownership of the database but the data center is responsible for
> managing the hardware.
>
> **Cloud Solution**
>
> The third option sees the vendor hosting the database in their own
> data centre.  In this case, the vendor is responsible for managing the
> hardware, the database, and the application updates.  The customer has
> no access to the physical database or raw data.

The "on-premises" clause means that the database
is installed in your location, and that you are
responsible and have full control of every aspect
of its environment.

Since the VM belongs to you, this is "on-premises".

Comment: This is different from what the wikipedia article mentions. I understand what you're saying, and it makes sense that it would work this way. But the wikipedia article specifically states that the software doesn't run on the cloud.

Comment: There is no conflict : "on-premises" is different than "Cloud Solution" according to both Wikipedia and my answer. Wikipedia says: "cloud-based software users only need to install an application or a web browser in order to access its services". This is different from "on-premises" where you can access the real/virtual computer directly. It doesn't mean that the "premises" cannot be in a rented/uploaded VM. The definition I quoted cuts through the confusion by defining it as a degree of control.